# Gráficos highcharts em php e mysql

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

Estou a tentar criar gráficos highcharts dinâmicos em php e mysql. Comecei por criar as consultas à base de dados:

```
$query = "SELECT Descricao, COUNT(Descricao) AS Tarefa  FROM raddb.Tarefa AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.TipoTarefa AS B ON B.Id = A.Tarefa 
GROUP BY Tarefa ORDER BY Descricao;";  

$viewer = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$viewer = mysqli_fetch_all($viewer,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$viewer = json_encode(array_column($viewer, 'count'),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Retorno:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segunda consulta:

```
$sql = "SELECT Colaborador, COUNT(Descricao) AS Tarefa  FROM raddb.Tarefa AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.TipoTarefa AS B ON B.Id = A.Tarefa 
GROUP BY Tarefa, Colaborador ORDER BY Descricao;";

    $click = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $click = mysqli_fetch_all($click,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $click = json_encode(array_column($click, 'count'),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois como crio o gráfico:

```
$(function () { 

    var data_click = <?php echo $click; ?>;
    var data_viewer = <?php echo $viewer; ?>;

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Yearly Website Ratio'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['2013','2014','2015', '2016']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Rate'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Click',
            data: data_click
        }, {
            name: 'View',
            data: data_viewer
        }]
    });
});


</script>


<div class="container">
    <br/>
    <h2 class="text-center">Highcharts php mysql json example</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="container"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Mas quando abro a página com o gráfico, fica em branco como mostro na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Algum erro é apontado no console?

Comment: @Darlei Fernando Zillmer  não aponta nehum erro na consola

Comment: @Darlei Fernando Zillmer penso que o problema está aqui, `$click = json_encode(array_column($click, 'count'),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);` e `$viewer = json_encode(array_column($viewer, 'count'),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`  porque faço `var_dump`ou `print_r` e imprimi null ou vazio.

Comment: Realmente, deve ser aí mesmo o problema, se suas variaveis nao tem nada, o grafico nao vai mostrar nada. Revisa as funções do banco, faz um debug bem na mão mesmo com var_dump nas funções do json_encode e array_column. Ativar o error_reporting também é uma boa caso não esteja ativado.

Comment: @Darlei Fernando Zillmer mas as queries estão corretas. O problema que estou a ter e não estou a conseguir entender, é como envio os dados das queries ou só uma querie para o gráfico, pode ajudar?

Comment: A passagem dos valores não está errada. O código é sequencial, se o php vier antes do JS, as variaveis serão setadas. Você testou as queries direto no banco ou no mysqli_query?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94347/discussion-between-bruno-and-darlei-fernando-zillmer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está no segundo parâmetro do `array_column`, você precisa definir uma coluna de valores a ser retornada, que no caso exista no `array` de retorno da consulta. Como você faz:

```
... COUNT(Descricao) AS Tarefa ...
```

Sua chave associativa é **Tarefa**, logo:

```
...
$viewer = json_encode(array_column($viewer, 'Tarefa'),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
...
$click = json_encode(array_column($click, 'Tarefa'),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); 
...
```

> Referência: Documentação [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php)

Comment: posso só lhe questionar uma pequeno coisa no chat?

Comment: Claro, pode sim